# The 'buildOptimizer' option cannot be used without 'aot'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

when I try to run the "ng serve" command I get the follow error:

[error] Error: The 'buildOptimizer' option cannot be used without 'aot'.

```
at generateWebpackConfig (C:\Users\Acasa\0 SDA\0 Proiecte practice\0 onlineMall\onlineMallApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:45:15)
at generateBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (C:\Users\Acasa\0 SDA\0 Proiecte practice\0 onlineMall\onlineMallApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:125:26)
at async generateI18nBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (C:\Users\Acasa\0 SDA\0 Proiecte practice\0 onlineMall\onlineMallApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:73:20)
at async setup (C:\Users\Acasa\0 SDA\0 Proiecte practice\0 onlineMall\onlineMallApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\dev-server\index.js:134:47)
```

I've been trying all solutions found on internet but no one worked for me. Many people suggested to make some changes into the angular.json file, but nothing worked for me.

This is my angular.json file content.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-ecommerce": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular-ecommerce",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot":true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-ecommerce:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-   ecommerce:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-ecommerce:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "angular-ecommerce:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "angular-ecommerce:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "angular-ecommerce",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In build options set

> "aot": true,